# Concrete meaning of 部 , 課 and 局

Tags: meaning, business-japanese, ambiguity

I can't figure out when referring to 部, 課 or 局 if we speak of an "organization of people" or "the place where they perform their job" ?

I have the same problem regarding the word 部局 even when I've checked the definition:

> ぶ-きょく [1] 【部局】
> 官庁や企業などの内部で，事務を分担する局・部・課などの総称。

I would like to understand the concrete meaning of those (somehow) abstract words and what they refer to.

Answer (score 2):

部局 is, as the definition says, a collective noun referring to divisions in an organization, so corresponds to plural *divisions, departments*.

As for 部, 課, 局, they are usually divisions/subdivisions hierarchically organized, depending on the organization.

For example, [Metropolitan Police Department](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AD%A6%E8%A6%96%E5%BA%81) has several 部, under which there are several 課.  On the other hand, [Ministry of Finance](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B2%A1%E5%8B%99%E7%9C%81) has several 局 and 課 below them. Both 部 and 局 seem to be translated as *bureau*.

I think in most traditional Japanese companies there are 部 and 課, but perhaps not 局. But again, this just depends.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! But (because my english is horrible ) does division can mean "the place where the inner suborganization works" or only that "suborganization"

Comment: @ZEa I guess so, but *department* may be more common. Anyway, *sales dept* would be 営業部, *public relations dept* 広報部 and so on. Note that generic company structures may be different between Japan and abroad, because of which translating *dept* as 部 may not look always natural.

Comment: 部,課,局 mean suborganizations themselves if that's what you're wondering.