# Example of a ～局, ～部 and ～課 in a company

Tags: words

**Could you please help me to find an example of a ～局, ～部 and ～課 in a company?**

Looking for the definition of ～部 in Jisho, it says ～部 refers to a department in a company, for example, 経理部 (accounting department), and as a little note, Jisho adds "above 課, below 局".

However, looking for ～局 and ～課 on Jisho, I can't find examples of ～局 and ～課 referring to divisions inside a company.

Then, my doubt would be the following.

1)
**For example, the 経理部 of a company, inside which ～局 it is?**

**And inside that 経理部, which several ～課 there are?**

2)
**Or as another example, the マーケティング部 of a company, inside which ～局 it is?**

**And inside that マーケティング部, which several～課 there are?**

As a side note, I've also consulted this post

[Concrete meaning of 部 , 課 and 局](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97496/concrete-meaning-of-%e9%83%a8-%e8%aa%b2-and-%e5%b1%80)

but if possible, I would like to find concrete examples of ～局, ～部 and ～課 in a company (or if not a company, in another type of organization) to illustrate these hierarchically organized divisions/subdivisions.

Comment: I guess it just varies from company to company. If you are just looking for examples, I doubt it's a language question. Rather it's about company organizations. Also, as far as I googled, the structure under 課 is not usually published for private companies.